# Is it possible to read the previous state of a row in a transaction?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have .NET code that creates a transaction and in this transaction, it performs an insert/update followed by validation.  If validation fails, an exception is thrown to rollback changes.

I need add an validation rule to this VB.NET code that require checking the current state and the previous state of a row (ie: the state before the insert/update). Basically my validation rule allows a state transition from A->B but not B->A.

How can I query the state of the row outside of the current transaction? In other words, can I query the state of the row before the insert/update?

Comment: Sounds like you want a trigger, which can do exactly that.

Comment: Why don't you just query the current state (select the row), do your validations and update/insert only if the validation succeeds? A trigger could also prevent the row from being inserted/updated (as pmbAustin said) but it would give you more/easier control to do the validation in code (e. g. for showing messages to the user, throwing exceptions or so). It's not neccessary to query the current state outside the transaction.

Comment: If you query the same data using a different SqlConnection, you'll see the data in the state before it changed in transaction. Is that what you want?

Comment: You can use `OUTPUT inserted.*, updated.*` with `ExecuteReader` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

Comment: @IngoB: Your suggestion is valid but it isn't easy to do. The code that performs the insert/update are in one assembly, the validation logic is another assembly and a MVC web app invokes the assemblies invokes the insert/update and validation in a transaction. All 3 assemblies do not communicate the state of the row/entity, only the ID of the row/entity that was modified. The assemblies get the row/entity by querying the database. It would be a massive undertaking to change this design. Thanks

Comment: @Flicker: I think your solution would work. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @T.S: This looks interesting. I'll give it a shot when I'm back in the office. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a stored procedure with return values. Inside the stored procedure you should first select the row you want to update, assign the variables you wan't to return, continue with your update (you could also validate here), and then return the assigned variables like this:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(Name varchar(50),Age int);
DECLARE @Name,
        @Age
BEGIN
    SET @Name = (SELECT Name from YourTable WHERE ID=1)
    SET @Age = (SELECT Age from YourTable WHERE ID=1)

    -- Here goes your update statement..

END

RETURN @MyTableVar
```

Comment: Your suggestion is valid but this solution isn't feasible with the current architecture of my app. I have mentioned how the code is organized in another comment above. Thanks